# uint8 little endian array to uint16 big endian

Tags: python, arrays, endianness, unsigned-integer, unsigned-char

In Python2.7, from an USB bulk transfer I get an image frame from a camera:

```
frame = dev.read(0x81, 0x2B6B0, 1000)
```

I know that one frame is 342x260 = 88920 pixels little endian, because that I read 2x88920 = 177840 (0x2B6B0) from the bulk transfer.

How can I convert the content of the frame array that is typecode=B into an uint16 big endian array?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
frame_short_swapped = array.array('H', ((j << 8) | i
                                        for (i,j)
                                        in zip(frame[::2], frame[1::2])))
```

It pairs two consecutive bytes from `frame` and unpacks that pair into `i` and `j`. Shift `j` one byte left and `or` it with `i`, effectively swap bytes (aka endianness conversion for 2 byte type) and feed that into an `H` type array. I am a bit uneasy about that bit, since it should correspond to C `short` type (according to docs), but type sizes really only guarantee minimal length. I guess you would need to introduce `ctypes.c_uint16` if strict about that?

Comment: nice, that seems to work, a little test with x = [3,103,3,103] converted it to array('H', [26371, 26371]), which was what I looking for. I will test it soon with my camera data. Sorry my english is bad but by your last sentence you mean I should use ctypes.c_uint16 for frame_short_swapped? Could I also use a numpy.uint16 array?

Comment: I just meant that if you strictly require`uint16`, typecode `H` (or `short`) does not guarantee that.  If you rely on that / it was a problem, you would have to go one step further and use something else to handle and store your values. Like `ctypes` or, yes, `numpy`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have probably added. It's not guaranteed that `short` is (only) 2 bytes long, but it actually is very likely and chances are on most system you encounter it is. :) In other words, depending on your use case, keep that in mind, but perhaps no action required (at least for now).